# problem with understanding a especial Structure in C

Tags: c, function, pointers, struct, boolean

i have problem with understanding below struct in c language !
i understand what is a struct and what it use for but this one seems weird for me and i can't see the standard form of struct like it's described in c learning websites like [www.geeksforgeeks.org](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org) !

It's nothing more in code about this struct !

```
typedef struct sIMasterConnection* IMasterConnection;

struct sIMasterConnection {
    bool (*isReady) (IMasterConnection self);
    bool (*sendASDU) (IMasterConnection self, CS101_ASDU asdu);
    bool (*sendACT_CON) (IMasterConnection self, CS101_ASDU asdu, bool negative);
    bool (*sendACT_TERM) (IMasterConnection self, CS101_ASDU asdu);
    void (*close) (IMasterConnection self);
    int (*getPeerAddress) (IMasterConnection self, char* addrBuf, int addrBufSize);
    CS101_AppLayerParameters (*getApplicationLayerParameters) (IMasterConnection self);
    void* object;
};
```

Comment: See [**How do function pointers in C work?**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/840501/how-do-function-pointers-in-c-work)

Comment: Understanding this has nothing to do with structs as such. As a side note, it is sometimes considered bad practice to dump a bunch of function pointers in a struct instead of using a separate "vtable", but that's an advanced topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All data members of the structure except this one

```
void* object;
```

are pointers to functions.

For example this data member

```
bool (*isReady) (IMasterConnection self);
```

declares a pointer to function that has return type `bool` and one parameter of the type `IMasterConnection` that is an alias for the pointer type declared like

```
typedef struct sIMasterConnection* IMasterConnection;
```

That is the parameter `self` has the type of a pointer to an object of the type `struct sIMasterConnection`.

To make it clear consider a simple demonstration program where there is declared a pointer to a function.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void f( void )
{
    puts( "Hello, World!" );
}

int main( void )
{
    void ( *pf )( void ) = f;

    pf();
}
```

The program output is

```
Hello, World!
```

A similar way as there is declared the saclar variable `pf` you may declare a data member of a struture.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void f( void )
{
    puts( "Hello, World!" );
}

int main( void )
{
    struct A
    {
        void ( *pf )( void );
    };

    struct A a = { .pf = f };

    a.pf();
}
```